# Remove a package (upday) from stock theme

Tags: root-access, apk, themes, samsung-galaxy-j3

I'm new to android so please forgive my maybe trivial questions.

So far I've been able to root my J3-2017 (TWRP+SuperSU+Nougat) and now I can access the internal file system using adb shell.

My purpose is to debloat my device. I've been able to manually delete Microsft apps (*) but I don't seem to find a way to remove UpDay which, apparently, is packaged inside the default theme.

The question is: does anybody know a way to remove such apps from a theme?

Thank you

(*) this is how I did remove Office:

```
adb shell 

su

mount -o rw,remount /system

find / -iname '*Excel*'

.

.

.

rm /data/data/com.microsoft.office.Excel

...
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, really a stupid question!

Actually the problem was that I could not find the correct package name for Upday. After a lot of google digging I've been able to discover the mistery.

The package is de.axelspringer.yana.zeropage (so where is "upday").

a normal `find / -iname '*axelspringer*'` (followed by `rm ...`) did the trick.